# Making background-image clickable

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a link out of the following so that the image is clickable.

What would you do to get the background-image clickable?

**HTML:** (Displays an Image which I would like clickable)

```
<div class="some_image">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.some_image{
    width: 200px;
    height:100px; 
    background-image: url(../images/image.png);
}
```

Comment: I would like it compatible with older browsers. So this might not work for for the moment?

Comment: If you want just the image area clickable, you must wrap the image with a link tag, or, if entire div can be clickable, you can add a click event to the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a background image clickable with HTML alone. It's a property of an element and not an element itself. Simply wrap the div in an anchor. This is permissible in HTML5 spec.

**[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)**

Of course, you could simply style the anchor:

```
.some_image {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height:100px; 
    background-image: url(../images/image.png);
}

<a class="some_image" href=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this traditionally *however* you may achieve the effect with hacky techniques:

```
#heatSpot { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; // over area of bg image
    top: 10px; // over area of bg image
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

then just fire the link or whatever your trying to do onClick with either wrapping above element in `<a>` tag -- or using jQuery / JavaScript.